# Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing **ORA-00971: missing SET keyword** error while running the below query,

```
UPDATE FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink
SET
FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink.Name = :1 ,
FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink.Description = :2
WHERE FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink.Id =:3;
```

Even though, the query looks fine with SET keyword, it throws the above error.
But,
It executes perfectly if I remove the alias name from the query.
Can anyone able to explain, why this behavior occurs when alias name is present in the above condition?

Comment: You appear to be aliasing FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink as itself - any reason? BTW this is oracle not mysql - if you want to attract oracle users change the tag.

Comment: Within a namespace, no two objects can have the same name. - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Comment: >You appear to be aliasing FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink as itself - any reason?          
   If query doesn't contain alias then, I am trying to specify alias as table name. So, in one of the cases, alias is not present and it is considering table name as alias

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the query doesn't look fine - you have two table names before "SET"

```
UPDATE FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink
```

Remove the duplicate table name to make it work:

```
UPDATE FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink
```

Comment: In my condition, I am specifying alias as table name if the alias is not specified explicitly. Is it wrong to specify table name as alias in UPDATE query?

Comment: @vivekhegde the you need to replace "@" with something else. Say, with "UPDATE FL_NOTIFICATION@notify_dblink FL_NOTIFICATION_notify_dblink"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works well.